# Is $\|h_n\|_{\mathcal{H}}$ bounded if $\{h_n\}$ converges in terms of sup norm?

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider an array of functions $\{h_n\}$ from a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. If we already know that $\{h_n\}$ converges to $h:\mathcal{X}\rightarrow R$ in terms of the sup norm, i.e., $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists N>0$, s.t. $\forall n > N,\quad \sup_x|h_n(x)-h(x)| < \epsilon$. Can we assert that $\|h_n\|_{\mathcal{H}}$ is bounded?

Can we get a general result without special assumptions on $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{H}}$ and $\mathcal{X}$?

Comment: What is $\cal X$? How are you defining $\|h_n\|_{\cal H}$?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Could we get a general conclusion without assumptions?

Comment: Have you tried constructing a counterexample in $L^2(\mathbb R)$?

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis I have tried but failed :) Have you succeeded and could you give me any clue for it?

Comment: @AndrewSong: just consider "rectangles", i.e. indicator functions of intervals. By letting the width grow very quickly while the height shrinks to zero you should get uniform convergence but diverging $L^2$ norm.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis. Thanks! I should have thought of that...